# Column name and row name matching in R

Tags: r, text, analytics

Newbie in R here. I do have columns from another data frame with the same name as of levels of b$Seasons below. Let's say dataX$Winter, dataX$Summer, dataX$Spring, and dataX$Fall.

I need to get such the value of the "Number" column if the column dataX$Summer is in the rownames of Seasons from data frame b.

```
> b
Seasons  Number
Winter      2
Summer      1
Spring      0
Fall        3
```

In here for Summer, I need to get 1, etc. Is there a way I could turn dataX$Summer into a string so I would be able to look into its values in b dataframe? Thank you

Comment: I can not use names(dataX) as I need to pass each column in a function one at a time. I just need dataX column names be string so I could compare it to B rownames

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to find Number for a given Season? If so, a solution using data.table might look like:

```
data.table(dataX)[Seasons == "Summer", Number]
```